# Custom sort name in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

Any idea how to change the default sort[0][field] & sort[0][dir] params into custom names like orderby & dir?

Based on the "Request URL" documentation, you can use the "dataSendParams" option to set alternative parameter names. But I tried this code but seems not to work:

```
dataSendParams:{
    "page":"pageNo",
    "size":"limitTo",
    "sort[0][field]":"orderBy",
    "sort[0][dir]":"dir",
},
```

Please help...I'm using the latest version 5.4

Comment: Any idea guys? Same this with filter can't set alternative parameter

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this:

```
dataSendParams:{
    "page":"pageNo",
    "size":"limitTo",
    "orderBy":"sort[0][field]",
    "dir":"sort[0][dir]"
},
```

Comment: Uhm.. I think the 1st sequence should be "sort[0][field]" before the new param name. the page and size already work as expected but not the sorting